# Como configurar meu htaccess?

Tags: apache

atualmente tenho um servidor linux no `linode.com`, onde tenho uma aplicação java rodando em um tomcat. Partindo disso, gostaria de realizar algumas configurações no arquivo `htaccess`. O meu problema é que no servidor não existe esse arquivo, então criei o mesmo na pasta raiz do servidor, porém a configuração não surgiu efeito. "Sei" que o arquivo httpd.conf do apache está apontando para ler esse arquivo.  Minha duvida é: onde devo criar esse arquivo `htaccess`, como fazer o apache ler tal configuração e aplicar essa configuração nos arquivos acessados da minha aplicação?

A conf do `htaccess` que estou tentando fazer é para adicionar expiração em arquivos estaticos do projeto: `css,js,img,...`

Meu Arquivo `apache2.conf`

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: [Veja se isso](https://paulund.co.uk/set-expire-headers-in-htaccess) te ajuda.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Então Ivan, a configuração eu tenho, porém ela não surge efeito nos arquivos, ao meu ver, o apache não está conseguindo "pegar" a conf.

Comment: Você deve criar dentro da pasta www do seu domínio. É assim em todos os meus servidores. Inclusive tá explicíto na regra do seu httpd.conf que é permitido reescrita de urls em /var/www

Answer (score 1):

Você deve criar seu arquivo `.htaccess` apartir de /var/www ou seja tb pode criar em subdiretórios dentro da raiz estipulada em seu httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

`AllowOverride All`, essa directiva habilita a rescrita de url apartir do diretorio informado acima.

Atualização :

O seu httpd.conf só tem essas três rotas nenhuma delas aponta para o destino aonde sua aplicação está.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

A solução mais viável que vejo é criar um novo `Directory` assim:

```
<Directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Isso deve resolver. Mas também poderia criar um atalho para o path aonde está sua aplicação dentro de /var/www como a opção FollowSymLinks está ativa o apache seguiria até o diretorio. Após adicionar a configuração reinicie o apache.

Comment: Rafael, adicionei nesse caminho, porém não surge efeito na aplicação. Não sei se tem a ver mas a aplicação e os arquivos ficam fora de /var/www/ e sim em /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Comment: Nesse caso eu acredito que tem que criar um symlink (atalho) dentro de /var/www para /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps,  e também habilitar no httpd.conf para seguir dentro da rota /var/www; caso contrário acredito que não irá funcionar. Ou então dentro de seu httpd.conf crie um Directory  novo com o caminho que disse que está a aplicação /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps e configure a sobrescrita acredito que também funcione.

Comment: Rafa, acabei colocando um redirect no htaccess afim de testar se realmente ao acessar o dominio ele iria fazer o redirect, porém sem sucesso. Talvez a configuração não está nem sendo lida. Como eu verifico isso?